# Strings like %2c in query string

Tags: c#, query-string

I log query string of a page. It's with `C#`.

How can i convert strings like `%2c%20` to a normal string in `C#` code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HttpUtility.UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If the string is in the current request's url-parameters, you can use [`Request.QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) to access it which decodes it implicitely. Otherwise use [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

HttpUtility.UrlDecode will do. Check this [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6196h3wt.aspx)